# functional interface with spark serialization issue

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, apache-spark

Consider the following spark code:

```java
package test 

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

abstract class Ops implements Serializable {

  public void doSomething(JavaRDD<Integer> rdd, Function<Integer, Integer> func) {
    rdd.map(x -> x + func.call(x))
       .collect()
       .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}

public class AbstractTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AbstractTest().job();
  }

  public void job() {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(AbstractTest.class.getName())
      .setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

    Ops ops = new Ops() {};

    Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = v1 -> v1 + 1; // works

    Function<Integer, Integer> f2 = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer call(Integer v1) throws Exception {
        return v1 + 1;
      }
    }; // java.io.NotSerializableException of non-serializable outer class

    ops.doSomething(rdd, f1);
  }
}
```

What I want to figure out is the different between functional interface and lambda expression in my case:

Basically, function `doSomething` in abstract class `Ops` needs to serialize a `spark.api.java.function.Function` which is already a serializable closure.

When initializing the `Function` object, I used two different ways:

- f1: lambda expression
- f2: explicit function interface

And f1 works, f2 doesn't. I find that they have different class name:

- f1: class test.AbstractTest$$Lambda$8/783882192
- f2: class test.AbstractTest$2

It seems that `f2` is compiled as an anonymous class whose serialization is strongly discouraged in java and its outer class needs to be serialized too. In my case, the outer class `AbstractTest` is not serializable. That's why we get a `NotSerializableException`.

On the other hand, `f1` is compiled as `$Lambda$8/783882192`, and I do not understand what it stands for. But apparently, it is a different implement from anonymous class. And it works fine. It seems that it can avoid serializing outer class.

So, what is the difference between functional interface and lambda expression ? It seems that they are not equivalent in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expressions are not *necessarily* implemented as inner classes, whereas the functional interface definitely is. Since your Lambda expression does not close over any class variables, it is more likely to end up as a static member.

This slideshare is quite good at explaining the design decisions of Lambdas, and the fact that the concrete implementation of your Lambda is delayed until runtime depending on various factors, some of which are JVM implementation specific https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwin3d7DkqHHAhWCWBQKHTLFAlA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2Fjaxlondon2012%2Flambda-a-peek-under-the-hood-brian-goetz&ei=1vnJVaeaGIKxUbKKi4AF&usg=AFQjCNFeoyEpSfx6qNFeCOQ9iFpSxarthg&bvm=bv.99804247,d.d24.

You might try the following, which causes `f1` to close over a class member, and see if you get a different outcome. In this case, it is not possible for `f1` to be a static member:

```
public int getIncrement() {return 1;}
Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = v1 -> v1 + getIncrement();
```

See if this gives you a different result.

Comment: I confirm that the result is different. `f1` does not work in your case. Thanks for the link.